# Undefined symbol in libboost

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

I see the following error

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so.1.57.0: 
undefined symbol: PyUnicode_AsUTF8String
```

In .so file I see the following symbol undefined

```
@Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal:/usr/local/lib$ nm libboost_python.so.1.57.0
| grep PyUnicode_AsUTF8String
             U PyUnicode_AsUTF8String
```

What could be the reason for this symbol to be undefined?

I checked also ldd and all libraries are in standard places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PyUnicode_AsUTF8String` function is part of python runtime. You should link your extension to python library too, by providing proper linker options to GCC. Please note that there are differences between python 3 and python 2.